# Jquery problem in IE

Tags: asp.net, jquery

when i am using mbScrollable.js file,my buttons are not working.when i click on button it is giving me error "State information is not valid".

when i comment this all buttons are working fine.
Is this the problem of mbScrollable.js file.i am using mbScrollable.js version: "1.5.7".It is giving problem in IE only.in mozilla it is working fine.

Can you please help me in finding error
my mbScrollable.js.

```
(function($) {   
    $.mbScrollable = {
        plugin: "mb.scrollable",
        author: "MB",
        version: "1.5.7",
        defaults: {
            dir: "horizontal",
            width: 950,
            elementsInPage: 4,
            elementMargin: 2,
            shadow: false,
            height: "auto",
            controls: "#controls",
            slideTimer: 600,
            autoscroll: false,
            scrollTimer: 6000,

            nextCallback: function() { },
            prevCallback: function() { }
        },

        buildMbScrollable: function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                this.options = {};
                $.extend(this.options, $.mbScrollable.defaults);
                $.extend(this.options, options);

                var mbScrollable = this;
                mbScrollable.isVertical = mbScrollable.options.dir != "horizontal";
                var controls = $(mbScrollable.options.controls);
                mbScrollable.idx = 1;
                mbScrollable.scrollTo = 0;
                mbScrollable.elements = $(mbScrollable).children();
                mbScrollable.elements.addClass("scrollEl");
                controls.hide();

                $(mbScrollable).children().each(function() { $(this).wrap("<div class='SECont'></div>"); });
                if (mbScrollable.options.shadow) {
                    $(mbScrollable.elements).css("-moz-box-shadow", mbScrollable.options.shadow);
                    $(mbScrollable.elements).css("-webkit-box-shadow", mbScrollable.options.shadow);
                }
                mbScrollable.elements = $(mbScrollable).children();
                var eip = mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage < this.elements.size() ? mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage : mbScrollable.elements.size();
                if (mbScrollable.isVertical) {
                    mbScrollable.singleElDim = (mbScrollable.options.height / eip) - mbScrollable.options.elementMargin;
                    $(mbScrollable.elements).css({ marginBottom: mbScrollable.options.elementMargin, height: mbScrollable.singleElDim, width: mbScrollable.options.width });
                } else {
                    mbScrollable.singleElDim = (mbScrollable.options.width / eip) - mbScrollable.options.elementMargin;
                    $(mbScrollable.elements).css({ marginRight: mbScrollable.options.elementMargin, width: mbScrollable.singleElDim, display: "inline-block", float: "left" }); //float:"left"


                }
                this.elementsDim = (mbScrollable.singleElDim * mbScrollable.elements.size()) + (mbScrollable.options.elementMargin * mbScrollable.elements.size());
                mbScrollable.totalPages = Math.ceil(mbScrollable.elements.size() / mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage);

                var adj = $.browser.safari && mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage > 2 ? mbScrollable.options.elementMargin / (mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage) : 0;

                if (mbScrollable.isVertical)
                    $(mbScrollable).css({ overflow: "hidden", height: mbScrollable.options.height - adj, width: mbScrollable.options.width, paddingRight: 5, position: "relative" });
                else
                    $(mbScrollable).css({ overflow: "hidden", width: mbScrollable.options.width - adj, height: mbScrollable.options.height, paddingBottom: 5, position: "relative" });

                var mbscrollableStrip = $("<div class='scrollableStrip'/>").css({ width: mbScrollable.elementsDim, position: "relative" });
                $(mbScrollable.elements).wrapAll(mbscrollableStrip);
                mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip = $(mbScrollable).find(".scrollableStrip");
                $(mbScrollable.elements).hover(
                function() {
                    //                  console.debug(mbScrollable.autoScrollActive);
                    if (mbScrollable.autoScrollActive)
                        $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll();
                },
                function() {
                    if (mbScrollable.autoScrollActive)
                        $(mbScrollable).mbAutoscroll();
                });
                if (mbScrollable.options.autoscroll && mbScrollable.elements.size() > mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage) {
                    mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = true;
                    $(mbScrollable).mbAutoscroll();
                }
                $(mbScrollable).mbPageIndex();
                $(mbScrollable).mbActivateControls();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".scrollEl").fadeIn();
                }, 1000);
                $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();
            });
        },

        mbNextPage: function(auto) {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            if (!auto) mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = false;

            if (mbScrollable.idx == mbScrollable.totalPages) {
                $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();
                return;
            }
            if (mbScrollable.options.nextCallback) mbScrollable.options.nextCallback();
            var adj = $.browser.safari && mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage > 2 ? mbScrollable.options.elementMargin / mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage : 0;
            mbScrollable.scrollTo -= ((mbScrollable.singleElDim + mbScrollable.options.elementMargin) * mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage) - adj;
            if (mbScrollable.isVertical) {
                if ((mbScrollable.scrollTo < -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.height))
                    mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.height;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginTop: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            } else {
                if ((mbScrollable.scrollTo < -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.width))
                    mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.width;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginLeft: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            }
            mbScrollable.idx += 1;
            $(this).mbManageControls();
        },

        mbPrevPage: function(auto) {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            if (!auto) mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = false;

            if (mbScrollable.idx == 1) {
                $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();
                return;
            }

            if (mbScrollable.options.prevCallback) mbScrollable.options.prevCallback();

            var adj = $.browser.safari && mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage > 2 ? mbScrollable.options.elementMargin / mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage : 0;
            mbScrollable.scrollTo += ((mbScrollable.singleElDim + mbScrollable.options.elementMargin) * mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage) + adj;

            if (mbScrollable.isVertical) {
                if (mbScrollable.scrollTo >= 0) mbScrollable.scrollTo = 0;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginTop: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            } else {
                if (mbScrollable.scrollTo >= 0) mbScrollable.scrollTo = 0;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginLeft: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            }
            mbScrollable.idx -= 1;
            $(this).mbManageControls();
        },

        mbFirstPage: function() {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = false;

            mbScrollable.scrollTo = 0;
            if (mbScrollable.isVertical) {
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginTop: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            } else {
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginLeft: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            }
            mbScrollable.idx = 1;
            $(this).mbManageControls();
            $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll();
        },

        mbLastPage: function() {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = false;

            if (mbScrollable.isVertical) {
                mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.height;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginTop: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            } else {
                mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.width;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginLeft: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
            }
            mbScrollable.idx = mbScrollable.totalPages;
            $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();
            $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll();
        },

        mbPageIndex: function() {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            var controls = $(mbScrollable.options.controls);
            var pages = controls.find(".pageIndex");
            if (pages) {
                function getPage(i) {
                    mbScrollable.scrollTo = -((mbScrollable.singleElDim + mbScrollable.options.elementMargin) * (mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage * (i - 1)));
                    if (mbScrollable.isVertical) {
                        if (mbScrollable.scrollTo < -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.height)
                            mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.height;
                        $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginTop: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
                    } else {
                        if (mbScrollable.scrollTo < -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.width)
                            mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.width;
                        $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginLeft: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, mbScrollable.options.slideTimer);
                    }
                    mbScrollable.idx = Math.floor(i);
                    $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();
                }
                var n = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i <= mbScrollable.totalPages; i++) {
                    n++;
                    var p = $("<span class='page'> " + n + " <\/span>").bind("click", function() {
                        getPage($(this).html());
                        $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll();
                        mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = false;
                    });
                    pages.append(p);
                };
            }
        },
        mbAutoscroll: function() {
            var dir = "next";
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = true;

            if (mbScrollable.autoscroll) return;
            var timer = mbScrollable.options.scrollTimer + mbScrollable.options.slideTimer;
            mbScrollable.autoscroll = true;
            mbScrollable.auto = setInterval(function() {
                dir = mbScrollable.idx == 1 ? "next" : mbScrollable.idx == mbScrollable.totalPages ? "prev" : dir;
                if (dir == "next")
                    $(mbScrollable).mbNextPage(true);
                else
                    $(mbScrollable).mbPrevPage(true);
            }, timer);
            $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();
        },

        mbStopAutoscroll: function() {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            mbScrollable.autoscroll = false;
            clearInterval(mbScrollable.auto);
            $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();

        },

        mbActivateControls: function() {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            var controls = $(mbScrollable.options.controls);
            controls.find(".first").bind("click", function() { $(mbScrollable).mbFirstPage(); });
            controls.find(".prev").bind("click", function() { $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll(); $(mbScrollable).mbPrevPage(); });
            controls.find(".next").bind("click", function() { $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll(); $(mbScrollable).mbNextPage(); });
            controls.find(".last").bind("click", function() { $(mbScrollable).mbLastPage(); });
            controls.find(".start").bind("click", function() { $(mbScrollable).mbAutoscroll(); });
            controls.find(".stop").bind("click", function() { $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll(); mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = false; });
        },

        mbManageControls: function() {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            var controls = $(mbScrollable.options.controls);
            if (mbScrollable.elements.size() <= mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage) {
                controls.hide();
            } else {
                controls.fadeIn();
            }
            if (mbScrollable.idx == mbScrollable.totalPages) {
                controls.find(".last").addClass("disabled");
                controls.find(".next").addClass("disabled");
            } else {
                controls.find(".last").removeClass("disabled");
                controls.find(".next").removeClass("disabled");
            }

            if (mbScrollable.idx == 1) {
                controls.find(".first").addClass("disabled");
                controls.find(".prev").addClass("disabled");
            } else {
                controls.find(".first").removeClass("disabled");
                controls.find(".prev").removeClass("disabled");
            }

            if (mbScrollable.autoscroll) {
                controls.find(".start").addClass("sel");
                controls.find(".stop").removeClass("sel");
            } else {
                controls.find(".start").removeClass("sel");
                controls.find(".stop").addClass("sel");
            }
            controls.find(".page").removeClass("sel");
            controls.find(".page").eq(mbScrollable.idx - 1).addClass("sel");
            controls.find(".idx").html(mbScrollable.idx + " / " + mbScrollable.totalPages);
        },

        goToPage: function(i, hasAnim) {
            var mbScrollable = $(this).get(0);
            var anim = hasAnim ? 0 : mbScrollable.options.slideTimer;
            if (i > mbScrollable.totalPages) i = mbScrollable.totalPages;
            mbScrollable.scrollTo = -((mbScrollable.singleElDim + mbScrollable.options.elementMargin) * (mbScrollable.options.elementsInPage * (i - 1)));
            if (mbScrollable.isVertical) {
                if (mbScrollable.scrollTo < -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.height)
                    mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.height;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginTop: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, anim);
            } else {
                if (mbScrollable.scrollTo < -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.width)
                    mbScrollable.scrollTo = -mbScrollable.elementsDim + mbScrollable.options.width;
                $(mbScrollable.mbscrollableStrip).animate({ marginLeft: mbScrollable.scrollTo }, anim);
            }
            mbScrollable.idx = Math.floor(i);
            $(mbScrollable).mbManageControls();
            $(mbScrollable).mbStopAutoscroll();
            mbScrollable.autoScrollActive = false;
        }

    };

    $.fn.mbScrollable = $.mbScrollable.buildMbScrollable;
    $.fn.mbNextPage = $.mbScrollable.mbNextPage;
    $.fn.mbPrevPage = $.mbScrollable.mbPrevPage;
    $.fn.mbFirstPage = $.mbScrollable.mbFirstPage;
    $.fn.mbLastPage = $.mbScrollable.mbLastPage;
    $.fn.mbPageIndex = $.mbScrollable.mbPageIndex;
    $.fn.mbgotoPage = $.mbScrollable.gotoPage;
    $.fn.mbAutoscroll = $.mbScrollable.mbAutoscroll;
    $.fn.mbStopAutoscroll = $.mbScrollable.mbStopAutoscroll;
    $.fn.mbActivateControls = $.mbScrollable.mbActivateControls;
    $.fn.mbManageControls = $.mbScrollable.mbManageControls;
    $.fn.goToPage = $.mbScrollable.goToPage;

    //  $.fn.mbAddElement=$.mbScrollable.mbAddElement;

})(jQuery1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for this code and add `float:"left"` as below in your JS file.

```
$(this.elements).css({
    marginRight: this.options.elementMargin,
    width: this.singleElDim,
    display: "inline-block",
    float:"left"
});
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a big view state, because the mb.scrollable keep all data on the same page, and usually this data are saved on viewstate.

To test that just check the source code of your rendered html to see if viewstate are real huge.

Then if it is just change the viewstate options on web.config. You can cut it in parts automatically on web.config. You can also find code on web that compress the viewstate. You can also disable the viewstate for your control and check if you do not have other problems and you do not needed.

Hope this help.